# What happens when .load() URL field is left blank

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying something like

`$('#select_addChannel').load("",function(){

some code;

}`

I want to know what will be the error and how it will behave?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#select_addChannel').load("", function (response, status, xhr) {
    if (status === 'error') {
        // Error handler here
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think that `""` is a perfectly acceptable URL which refers to the current page.

So there's no reason why you would get an error.

Answer (score 0):

When the empty string is passed to the [URL resolution algorithm](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/urls.html#document-base-url), it is handled as a relative URL - which just points to the current page.